# Android | Inflated Buttons don't work

Tags: java, android, android-layout

> I inflate my layout with this code:

```
   FrameLayout frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.activity_frame);

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View activityView5 = layoutInflater.inflate(activity_start_home, null, false);

        frameLayout.addView(activityView5);
```

> The XML-Layout I inflate looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.musictrainer.music_trainer.StartHome">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/background"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_start_home" />

  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> The included "content" from this layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.musictrainer.music_trainer.StartHome"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_start_home">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/inton_but"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
    android:background="@color/buttons"
    android:text="Intonation"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/tuner_but"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:background="@color/buttons"
    android:text="Tuner"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inton_but" />
  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

So when I inflate the layout it displays the layout, but the buttons don't work. Do I have to inflate the buttons too? Do I have to inflate the content?

Comment: post your java code which button is not working

Comment: Button inton = findViewById(R.id.inton_but); But do I have to inflate it too?

Comment: Post the relevant code which according to you is not working.

Comment: inton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent i1 = new Intent(StartHome.this, Inton.class);
                startActivity(i1);

            }
        });

Comment: Since you're apparently trying to inflate an activity, why don't you simply use `setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_home)` in your `onCreate`?

Comment: @AlanC92 Because I use a Navigation Drawer which has a FrameLayout. This will be used to display the chosen layout.

Answer (score 0):

If you're changing the layout according to the navigation item I suggest you to use a fragment

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments

Please accept my answer if it solves your problem